# How to find a shape is closed shape or not?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing a game where i need to create different closed shapes using given number of Matchsticks MovieClip. So can anyone help me to find whether the shape created by user is Closed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a grid and the matchsticks occupy tiles from grid. Apply a simple pathfinding algorithm (any will do, get a simple one) from the center of the shape to a point outside of it. If the pathfinding fails, means its a closed shape. If it reaches the goal, means there is a path to it, means its not a closed shape.

Comment: Can you please tell how to access the center of the Shape....?For Example a Triangle or a Rectangle ? Please Reply....

Comment: If you turn the game into a grid, like I sugested, simply divide by 2 the width and height, there will be a cell (rounded down) which is the center. If not, calculate the x, y, width, height of the shape (or if the matchsticks are in a sprite, get x,y,width,height from it directly) and divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your strokes are 1 pixel thick.

1. Take any pixel on the line.
2. Take its 4-neighbours (call them 4N).
3. Use [`BitmapData.flooFill`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill%28%29) on each pixel of 4N.
4. Then for each of them, check if the flood fill coloured the 3 other ones. If it did then your shape is not closed. If at least one neighbour stays clear in at least one of the 4 `floodFills`, the shape is closed.

Comment: Will try and let u know the result .. Thanks for the answer

Comment: you presume the matchsticks's pixels connect, that they are all the same solid color, etc. if user2431915 is using raster graphics, this method does not work.